# CPU Usage Becomes Very High During Execution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, cpu

I recently built a service uses a single thread to process information periodically. The service was built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express. I noticed the CPU usage took off to the moon (CPU usage at 100%).

Later, out of curiosity, I built a very small program, in which all it does is start a small thread, or timer, then runs some incredibly long loop. I also switched from building a console application to a Windows Form application. I was able to reduce my trouble by switching the type of program to build.

I've tried lowering the priority of the thread:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
```

I've also tried to set the priority class

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
```

I also thought that the CPU usage could've been high due to running on a virtual machine. But that theory didn't take me anywhere. It's pretty ridiculous. I don't know where else to turn. I'm not sure why starting a timer or a thread would send my CPU usage through the ceiling the way it does in the .NET framework. I never experienced this when building COM objects. Does anyone have any bright ideas as to where I can turn?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looping repeatedly in your thread it could definitely cause high CPU usage. Have you tried adding a pause to your thread execution between loops?

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: The Thread.Sleep(1000) helped me make sense of everything. The real program is somewhat complex. This is part of the very small program I wrote:

System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc));
th.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
th.Start();

public static void ThreadFunc()
{
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
or (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

Comment: The intent of the original program was to process information, but it has to run often (e.g. 1/2 hr, or one hour). I see the Windows Scheduler only allows me to schedule a task only as frequently as daily. I thought I'd use a thread to keep track of the schedule, but I'm beginning to sense that's not turning out to be very clever. So I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I think I may turn around and use a Windows Task Scheduler instead instead of trying to do my own thing and use threads and timers in order to keep my program lightweight. 


Thanks guys and good looking out.

Comment: What about:    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;

Comment: I remember trying that. It seemed to have no effect. Given the nature of that particular project, in which it was to operate periodically, I think I ended up scheduling a task through the Windows Task Scheduler. I believe I was also able to reduce the CPU usage. I must track down the project + and the time in which I started this thread and share some source code in hopes of helping someone.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your code is looping infinitely and unexpectedly.

Start it in the Visual Studio debugger and when you see the high CPU, hit 'Break' to pause execution.  The callstacks and other program state you see when you do this repeatedly should give you an idea of what is wrong with your logic.

It's possible that simply stepping through the code in the debugger would be quicker.  It depends on how complex the code is.